# General purpose .NET templating engine that works in medium trust and .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, templates, .net-3.5, template-engine

Does anyone know of a good general purpose templating engine for .NET that also works in medium trust environments and .NET 3.5?  I've taken quick looks at NHaml, Razor, Spark, and StringTemplate.

I would love to use NHaml based on what I've seen so far, but it doesn't support medium trust environments and doesn't appear to be a very active project.

Comment: What are the limitations of the templating engines that you looked at so far in terms of medium trusted environments?

Comment: Nhaml for example, just won't run, throws up a .NET security/policy exception in a YSOD. I'm guessing due to reflection or some on the fly compilation it's trying to do in nhaml?